# Bathymetric data of European lakes

Tags: geospatial, europe

I'm looking for open bathymetric raster data of various European lakes. While it is relatively easy to find the high-quality bathymetric sea and ocean data ([7.5 arcsec data, for those interested](http://www.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/content/content.asp?menu=0040000_000000)), I have a lot of trouble finding this data for lakes (preferably 7.5 arcsec or more detailed).

In specific, I'm looking for data of these lakes:

- Lac Leman (CH/FR)
- Lac d'Annecy (FR)
- Lac du Bourget (FR)
- Lago Maggiore (IT)
- Lago d'Orta (IT)
- Lago Trasimeno (IT): [I found contour data for this lake](http://dati.umbria.it/dataset/batimetria-lago-trasimeno/resource/74619689-4705-420a-afcc-80c9e755f964)
- Lago di Bolsena (IT)